# Space between two rows of images in separate divs, only occurring on one particular row

Tags: css, image, html, space

(First: I have already tried all options involving margin, border, and so on.)

[Link to problematic page.](http://cs.okstate.edu/~lloydo/portal/level_-3.php)

[Link to similarly constructed, non-problematic page.](http://cs.okstate.edu/~lloydo/portal/)

This is made up of several divs and smaller images. The problem can be seen in the inventory boxen - there is a gap between the two rows.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset='UTF-8'>
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../style.css'>
      <title>Open the door</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class='puzzle'>
         <img src='images/lm1top.png' alt='img'>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class='puzzle'>
         <!-- THE PROBLEM IS HERE! -->
         <img src='images/lm1left_top.png' alt='img'>
         <img src='images/lm1key.png' id='key' alt='img'>
         <img src='images/lm1_x.png' alt='img'>
         <img src='images/lm1_1.png' id='num' alt='img'>
         <img src='images/lm1right_top.png' alt='img'>
         <!-- END PROBLEM -->
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class='puzzle'>
         <img src='images/lm1mid_top.png' alt='img'>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class='puzzle'>
         <img src='images/lm1door.png' id='door' alt='img'>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class='puzzle'>
         <img src='images/lm1body.png' alt='img'>
      </div>
      <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the stylesheet:

```
body
{
   background-color: black;
}

div.puzzle
{
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 50%;
}

div.puzzle img
{
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   margin: 0px;
   left: -50%
}

p
{
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}

div.hint p
{
   font-style: italic;
   font-size: 75%;
}

br
{
   clear: both;
}
```

It is notable that this happened below the only row with more than one image. The images in the problematic row are all the same height, and the combined width of the images is the same as the rows above and below. I checked several times.

I did the same thing on another page, but with no problem at all:

This page is broken into about as many pieces as the other, and it is broken at more than one place. But, it looks just fine, while the other has this annoying gap.

Any ideas as to the cause would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After seeing the Zelda screens: You had my curiosity. Now you have my attention. :P

Comment: Haha, if I ever finish it, it will be an JAOR-esque puzzle with plenty of retro game references. I thought it would be a fun way to practice HTML5, Javascript, and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the `<br>` elements that are between the `<div class="puzzle">` elements. Then add

```
clear: left
```

to the `.puzzle` selector.

[image]

Comment: It's magic! Thank you very much for helping a hacky CSS know-nothing.